# How to SELECT DISTINCT() and then keep rows with most frequent value in another column?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, group-by, count

Sample table columns:

```
  x    y
255    0
255    0
  5   10
  5    0
  5    1
  5    0
255    0
255    0
  2    5
  2    2
  2    5
255    0
```

The first step is to identify unique values of X:

```
SELECT distinct(X) FROM nodes ORDER BY X
```

Result:

```
  2
  5
255
```

Note: Order by isn't necessary, it's there to make the result easier to read.

For each of these values in column x, I would like to find the most frequent value in column y (only for the rows sharing the same X value, not the entire table) and output that single row.

I can do that by hand very easily:

```
  SELECT x, y, COUNT(y) AS 'n' 
    FROM nodes 
   WHERE x = 2           /* Manually edit this number to get desired result */
GROUP BY y 
ORDER BY COUNT(y) DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
when x = 2        2, 5, 2
when x = 5        5, 0, 2
when x = 255    255, 0, 5
```

Note: I don't need to output `COUNT(y) AS 'n'`.  It's included here to make it easier to see what's going on.

I can do this in Python by iterating through the unique x values from the first query and plugging that number into the second query each loop.  I can also just use a query like this and do all the work in Python:

```
SELECT x, y FROM nodes ORDER BY x
```

I would prefer to do it all in one query with SQL.

Is there a way to express this idea of "for each x in query #1, run query #1 with x in the WHERE clause" to deliver a single result out of one query operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x, 
       FIRST_VALUE(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) y
FROM tablename
GROUP BY x, y;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=1485dd19ef83e5900cf52c26600c83b0).

Comment: I see the demo you posted produces the right result.  However, for some reasons, on my system I get 10 for x = 5.  Also, PyCharm's SQL console complains that "Column INTENSITY is shadowed by alias" for the "intensity" after "DESC )".  I changed it to "DESC) AS intensity" and it's happy, but the result is still wrong.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @martin's do you mean that you test the query with the exact same data and you get different results?

Comment: Exactly.  The data is the same and I get a different result.  2, 5; 5, 10; 255, 0

Comment: @martin's this is not possible. Can you reproduce your results with your table definition and sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39?

Comment: I used the expressions from the demo you provided to add and populate a table to the db on my system and then run the query.  In this case, the result is correct.  The data on the actual table (which is larger and has more columns and rows) is the same for the sample I provided. The column data types are "int" rather than "integer", I don't think that makes a difference. Other than the warning about the "y" column being shadowed I am not sure what's going on.  I was going to post a link a a screenshot but imgur seems to be having trouble at the moment.

Comment: @martin's I suspect that the data is different. Execute this: `SELECT x,  y, COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY x, y;` and check the results.

Comment: Data is the same.  Here's a picture:  https://i.imgur.com/ciF3Rhz.png

Comment: Showing real table and column names in that case.  Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @martin's run a `PRAGMA integrity_check;` on the database to check for corruption, just in case.

Comment: It's returns OK

Comment: @martin's load the db in a tool like DB Browser for SQLite: https://sqlitebrowser.org and run the query. If the results are correct this means that the problem is your current software. Or export the table in a csv and post it here so I can test.

Comment: Tried in DB Browser for SQLite and got a syntax error.  In frustration I rebooted the computer.  Well.  Now the result is correct for exactly the same SQL statement.  Makes me wonder if the many attempts I made to come-up with a solution prior to posting on SO did not deliver results for the same reason.